# Disable internal routing

Tags: iptables, rules

I have 4 different subnets that go in to one Linux box that have openswan and configured VPN's. In the linux box i have configured one interface that is public and sub interfaces that are private. For example

```
eth0   - 1.1.1.1
eth0:0 - 192.168.0.1
eth0:1 - 192.168.1.1
etc...
```

And PC from 192.168.0.1 can reach PC that is on 192.168.1.1. I need to disable this type of communication. Iptables is the answer as i know but im confused about the rule how should be implement. Or if there is some other way to do it it will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to use the wrong tool for the job. The proper tool to use for the job would be VLAN tagging.

You can use the `vconfig` command to configure different VLANs on the network interface. For example you can create `eth0.1` with the command `vconfig add eth0 1`.

Using those instead of interface aliases, you can achieve real separation between the subnets. It requires a managed switch tough. I think what you are trying to do is impossible without a managed switch.

Once that is in place, you can use `iptables` rules to filter traffic between the subnets.

Comment: Because i want to avoid downtime i was hoping to resolve this with iptables, but i'm guess i'll go with vlan configuration anyway ... thanks.

Comment: Hi, i need an iptables rules for this purpose. I can't use VLANs in this scenario. Is there any way to do this ?